# zLib linking error XCode 4, undefined symbols

Tags: xcode, linker-errors, zlib, dylib

link err:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:  "_unzOpen", referenced from:
```

I have a libz.dylib in my xcode project (Build Phases/Link binaries with library)
also can see -lz link flag

```
Ld Debug/DemoOSX_d.app/Contents/MacOS/DemoOSX_d normal i386
cd /Projects/Scorpio/DemoOSX
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -L/Projects/Scorpio/DemoOSX/Debug -L/Projects/Scorpio/DemoOSX/../LibMacOS -F/Projects/Scorpio/DemoOSX/Debug -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/lib -filelist /Projects/Scorpio/DemoOSX/Debug/DemoOSX.build/Objects-normal/i386/DemoOSX_d.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -lz /Projects/Scorpio/DemoOSX/../LibMacOS/SysAudio_d.a /Projects/Scorpio/DemoOSX/../LibMacOS/SysUtils_d.a -lexpat -logg -lvorbis -lvorbisfile /Projects/Scorpio/DemoOSX/../LibMacOS/SysMath_d.a /Projects/Scorpio/DemoOSX/../LibMacOS/SysMemManager_d.a -framework OpenAL -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -o /Projects/Scorpio/DemoOSX/Debug/DemoOSX_d.app/Contents/MacOS/DemoOSX_d
```

1) tried check extension in file inspector - mach o dynamic library

2) tried build 32/64 bit app

3) add other linker flags "usr/lib/libz.dylib"

4) tried add header search path  /usr/include

nothing help:(, probably need to build itself

ARCHS 32bit intel
SDK_ROOT Latest 10.7
GCC_VERSION Apple LLVM 3.0

Answer (score 2):

The `unzOpen` function is part of "minizip", an add-on to zlib that is not included in Apple's version of zlib.  You need to go to zlib.net to get the source code for minizip.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that,  I'll build the library self.

Comment: how to build library . I didn't find any library on zlib.net . I only found the source code for this.